# WebRTC ICE candidate (Cannot Read Property)

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, webrtc, peer

I'm coding a Voice/Audio conference app using WebRTC (HTML+Javascript)
When I run the 2 clients, they successfully connect to the same room, the first one is the Initiator or creator of the room, the other one is a "guest" with a different ID. If I start the webcam call from by the Guest side, it works fine, i can see both the webcams and I can hear each side, BUT if I start by the Initiator side it gave me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdpMid' of null   main.js:178
at handleIceCandidate (main.js:178)
at RTCPeerConnection.wrappedCallback (adapter-latest.js:5259)
```

What could be the problem? 
CODE:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


 <title>Realtime communication with WebRTC</title>  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <div>
  <!-- style 'display = none' -->
    <button id = "chiama" onclick = "chiama()">Chiama</button><br/>
    <button id = "createId" onclick = "createId()">create ID</button>
  </div>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>

  </div>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
'use strict';

var isChannelReady = false;
var isInitiator = false;
var isStarted = false;
var localStream;
var pc;
var remoteStream;
var turnReady;
var constraints = { audio: true, video: true };

var pcConfig = {
  'iceServers': [{
    'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};

// Set up audio and video regardless of what devices are present.
var sdpConstraints = {
  offerToReceiveAudio: true,
  offerToReceiveVideo: true
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////

var room = prompt('Enter room name:');

var socket = io.connect();

if (room !== '') {
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
  console.log('Attempted to create or  join room', room);
}

socket.on('created', function(room) {
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  isInitiator = true;
  window.location.hash = 1111;
});

socket.on('full', function(room) {
  console.log('Room ' + room + ' is full');
});

socket.on('join', function (room){
  console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' + room);
  console.log('This peer is the initiator of room ' + room + '!');
  isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('joined', function(room) {
  console.log('joined: ' + room);
  isChannelReady = true;
  let clientId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      window.location.hash = clientId;
});

socket.on('log', function(array) {
  console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendMessage(message) {
  console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
  socket.emit('message', message);
}

// This client receives a message
socket.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log('Client received message:', message);
  if (message === 'got user media') {
    maybeStart();
  } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
      maybeStart();
    }
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    doAnswer();
  } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
      sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
      candidate: message.candidate
    });
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  } else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
    handleRemoteHangup();
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

//BOTTONE CHIAMA
function chiama() {
// document.getElementById('chiama').addEventListener('click', function() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(gotStream)
.catch(function(e) {
  alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
});
}

//BOTTONE GENERA ID 
function createId(){
// document.getElementById('createId').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let clientId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        window.location.hash = clientId;
        // getId.style.display = "none";
        // chiama.style.display = "inline";
// })
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localStream = stream;
  localVideo.srcObject = stream;
  sendMessage('got user media');
  if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
}

console.log('Getting user media with constraints', constraints);


function maybeStart() {
  console.log('>>>>>>> maybeStart() ', isStarted, localStream, isChannelReady);
  if (!isStarted && typeof localStream !== 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
    console.log('>>>>>> creating peer connection');
    createPeerConnection();
    pc.addStream(localStream);
    isStarted = true;
    console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
    if (isInitiator) {
      doCall();
    }
  }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  sendMessage('bye');
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
    return;
  }
}

function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('icecandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage({
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate

    });
  } else {
    console.log('End of candidates.');
  }
  console.log('ICEID: ' + event.candidate.sdpMid)
}

function handleCreateOfferError(event) {
  console.log('createOffer() error: ', event);
}

function doCall() {
  console.log('Sending offer to peer');
  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
}

function doAnswer() {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  pc.createAnswer().then(
    setLocalAndSendMessage,
    onCreateSessionDescriptionError
  );
}

function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message', sessionDescription);
  sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}

function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
  trace('Failed to create session description: ' + error.toString());
}

//Turn Server, viene usato da ICECandidate se Stun non tiene la connessione
function requestTurn(turnURL) {
  var turnExists = false;
  for (var i in pcConfig.iceServers) {
    if (pcConfig.iceServers[i].urls.substr(0, 5) === 'turn:') {
      turnExists = true;
      turnReady = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!turnExists) {
    console.log('Getting TURN server from ', turnURL);
    // No TURN server. Get one from computeengineondemand.appspot.com:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var turnServer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log('Got TURN server: ', turnServer);
        pcConfig.iceServers.push({
          'urls': 'turn:' + turnServer.username + '@' + turnServer.turn,
          'credential': turnServer.password
        });
        turnReady = true;
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', turnURL, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  remoteStream = event.stream;
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
}

function handleRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
}

function hangup() {
  console.log('Hanging up.');
  stop();
  sendMessage('bye');
}

function handleRemoteHangup() {
  console.log('Session terminated.');
  stop();
  isInitiator = false;
}

function stop() {
  isStarted = false;
  pc.close();
  pc = null;
}
```

index.js (server):

```
'use strict';

var os = require('os');
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');

var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8096);

var io = socketIO.listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  // convenience function to log server messages on the client
  function log() {
    var array = ['Message from server:'];
    array.push.apply(array, arguments);
    socket.emit('log', array);
  }

  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    log('Client said: ', message);
    // for a real app, would be room-only (not broadcast)
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
  });

  socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
    log('Received request to create or join room ' + room);

    var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    var numClients = clientsInRoom ? Object.keys(clientsInRoom.sockets).length : 0;

    if (numClients === 0) {
      socket.join(room);
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
      log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + (numClients+1) + ' client(s)');
      socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);

    } else if (numClients === 1) {
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
      log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + (numClients+1) + ' client(s)');
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
      socket.join(room);
      socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready');

    } else { // max two clients
      socket.emit('full', room);
    }
  });

  socket.on('ipaddr', function() {
    var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (var dev in ifaces) {
      ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details) {
        if (details.family === 'IPv4' && details.address !== '127.0.0.1') {
          socket.emit('ipaddr', details.address);
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Deleting console.log('ICEID: ' + event.candidate.sdpMid)
I solved the Initiator error but now I get another error in the Guest side. Both keep showing me the webcams, they are in the same room, but i can't see the other cam.
The error code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRemoteDescription' of undefined
    at n.<anonymous> (main.js:78)
    at n.emit (universalModuleDefinition:2)
    at n.onevent (universalModuleDefinition:3)
    at n.onpacket (universalModuleDefinition:3)
    at n.<anonymous> (universalModuleDefinition:3)
    at n.emit (universalModuleDefinition:2)
    at n.ondecoded (universalModuleDefinition:1)
    at s.<anonymous> (universalModuleDefinition:3)
    at s.r.emit (universalModuleDefinition:1)
    at s.add (universalModuleDefinition:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

event.candidate can be null. Move your

`console.log('ICEID: ' + event.candidate.sdpMid)`

inside the `if (event.candidate)` block and you should be good.

Comment: I deleted that console.log and nothing changed. The problem IMHO is that the Guest never create a candidate and it gives an error on the Initiator side.

Comment: did you ever figure it out? I'm having a similar problem and no idea what to do short of following the code. Thanks